# Laravel - Auth not working. super weird

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

Here's my authentication, it's not working. `Auth::attempt` returns bool `false`.
I've spent an hour on this problem. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```php
Route::get('/test', function() 
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = 'cake@cake.com';
    $user->password = Hash::make('cake');
    $user->save();

    var_dump(Auth::attempt(array('email' => 'cake@cake.com', 'password' => 'cake')));
    die;
});
```

Comment: Is it Laravel 3 or 4?

Comment: 4. Solved now though. stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue comes up when removing the default methods on the User model.

No exceptions are thrown it just stops working. Stupid, in hindsight.

Comment: Which default methods?

Comment: He probably means the methods implemented from `UserInterface` and `RemindableInterface`