# Laravel 6.2 Auth-scaffold - not working but doesn't throw / log error

Tags: vue.js, authentication, routes, laravel-6.2

**Problem**

I have added the Auth scaffolding to an existing project.

```
    php artisan ui vue --auth
```

From what I understand, the authentication should work out of the box without any prerequisites.
The views / urls are working fine, but neither the register process nor the login process are not working.
If not authenticated *my-domain.com/home* redirects me, as expected to *my-domain.com/login*.

Notices, warnings and exceptions for other issues are generally thrown as expected.
But I do not get errors thrown on this particular issue (register / login).
So I am bit lost here and happy for any help.

TIA

**Use case**

I'll fill out the form and will be redirected to the same page.
(e.g. my-domain.com/register will redirect me to my-domain.com/register).
Also a new user won't be inserted into the users table and reading fails in the process of a login, too.

**What I tried so far**

Permissions don't seem to be a problem as the script can create a user like so:

```
    $user = new \App\User;

    $user->name = 'Simon the Sorcrerer';
    $user->email = 'sorcerersimon@gme.co';
    $user->password = Hash::make('expelliarmus');
    $user->role_id = 'user';

    $user->save();
```

These links seem to me outdated in regards of the approach.
However - it might be worth to mention, that I did not change the Controller or anything else related to default values.

[2017 - Auth should work out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44536937/4474165) .
[2013 - Laravel - Auth not working. super weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389110/laravel-auth-not-working-super-weird)

I have tried

```
     Auth::routes();
     Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

and

```
     Auth::routes(['register' => true]);
     Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

and

```
     Auth::routes(['register' => true, 'verify' =>false]);
     Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

both without a change in the current behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: Mixed content behind a load balancer / CDN and missing role_id in query**

If you setup Laravel in a load balanced environment the https session terminates before it hits the web server so Laravel was serving for a http request, thus generating mixed content issues.
Hence the actual script does not get imported and the app itself does not throw any errors.

So you need to make sure that imported scripts and endpoints are served over a secure connection (https).

(You will see the mixed content error by checking the app in your browser's console.)

**Solving routing to insecure endpoints**

Edit your routing in:

```
app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
```

from

```
public function boot()
{
    ...
}
```

to

```
public function boot()
{
   // if (!\App::environment('local')) {
   \URL::forceScheme('https');
   // } 
}
```

The commented part is reflecting [Mladen Janjetovic's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37524373/4474165) if you like to differentiate between a local environment and production environment on a server.
However consider it a good practice to test locally as close as possible mimicking your production environment.

**Optional: Solving mixed content for script imports (CSS & JS)**

You want to make sure that scripts will be called from a secure source (https).
Edit your asset calling in:

```
resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
```

from

```
asset( ... )
```

to

```
secure_asset( ... )
```

**Solving missing default value when creating User**

As soon as you have solved mixed contents, you might see, that the *User::create* query fails. If that happens you probably want to do the following changes.

Edit your User model in:

```
app/User.php
```

from

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];
```

to

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'role_id'
];
```

Edit your query in:

```
app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php
```

from

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

to

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role_id' => $data['role_id'] ?? 'user' 
    ]);
}
```